# where is my misunderstanding regarding two very simple set theory results?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following two statements are intuitively easy to see as true.

1. $(A \subseteq B) \implies (A \cup B = B)$
2. $(A \subseteq B) \implies (A \cap B = A)$

I'm trying to prove the statements, using only basic axioms and definitions provided as part of Chapter 3 of Terence Tao's Analysis I, but am evidently failing.

**Question - where is the error in my logic below?**

---

**1. Show $(A \subseteq B) \implies (A \cup B = B)$**

Let's start with the definition of $A \cup B$,

$$ x \in (A \cup B) \implies (x \in A) \lor (x \in B) $$

By hypothesis we have $A \subseteq B$, which is defined as

$$ (A \subseteq B) \implies [(x \in A) \implies (x \in B)]$$

Or more simply, whenever we have $x\in A$, we can substitute $x \in B$.

So, substituting into the definition of union, we have

$$\begin{align}x \in (A \cup B) &\implies (x \in A) \lor (x \in B) \\ \\ &\implies (x \in B) \lor (x \in B) \\ \\ & \implies x \in B \end{align}$$

So $A \cup B = B$ if we're given $A \subseteq B$. $\square$

---

**2. Show $(A \subseteq B) \implies (A \cap B = A)$**

Let's start with the definition of $A \cap B$,

$$ x \in (A \cap B) \implies (x \in A) \land (x \in B) $$

By hypothesis we have $A \subseteq B$, which is defined as

$$ (A \subseteq B) \implies [(x \in A) \implies (x \in B)]$$

Or more simply, whenever we have $x\in A$, we can substitute $x \in B$.

So, substituting into the definition of intersection, we have

$$\begin{align}x \in (A \cap B) &\implies (x \in A) \land (x \in B) \\ \\ &\implies (x \in B) \land (x \in B) \\ \\ & \implies x \in B \end{align}$$

So $A \cap B = B$ if we're given $A \subseteq B$. $ **This is clearly wrong !**

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just not what you want! It's absolutely true that if $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in B$. You don't have *equality*, though, because you only have implications. You proved $A\cap B\subseteq B$. Note that technically you did not prove $A\cup B=B$ **either**. You only proved $A\cup B\subseteq B$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think that should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors: namely, when you conclude that your implications yield that $A\cup B=B$ in the first part, and when you conclude that your implications yield $A\cap B=B$ in the second part. The rest is correct.

In the first part, you correctly derive $x\in B$ from $A\subseteq B$ and $x\in A\cup B$. Thus, you correctly prove that under the assumption that $A\subseteq B$, then
$$x\in A\cup B\implies x\in B.$$
But note that this is not the definition of $A\cup B=B$; this is just the definition of $A\cup B\subseteq B$. So when you say

> So $A\cup B=B$ if we're given $A\subseteq B$. $\Box$

this is actually unwarranted. You have only proven $A\cup B\subseteq B$. Now, the fact is that $B\subseteq A\cup B$ is easy to show, of course, so that tells you that you have both $A\cup B\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$, which gives equality. But technically you "jumped the gun" in part 1.

But it is precisely that "jumping the gun" which is leading you astray in the second part. You correctly show, in the second part, that
$$x\in A\cap B\implies x\in B.$$
(You are invoking the additional assumption that $A\subseteq B$, but you don't need that; from $x\in A\wedge x\in B$ you could have just implie $x\in B$ directly, without substituting $x\in B$ for $x\in A$).

What does this prove? It does not prove, as you state, that $A\cap B=B$. What it proves is that $A\cap B\subseteq B$.

*Which is absolutely true!*

But not what you want to prove. You are concluding equality by making the same error you did in the first part, and ignoring that you only have one inclusion.

Instead, you should prove that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ (which is easy, and uses the fact that if $(Q\wedge R)\implies Q$); and then use the fact that $A\subseteq B$ to show that $A\subseteq A\cap B$ (e.g., by using the fact that $Q\implies (Q\wedge Q)$).

Comment: thank you for explaining the root of my misunderstanding (and not just providing a proof)

Answer (score 0):

The proofs of these can be done easily from first principles and with less symbols.

For 2.

To prove that $A\cap B=A$ show that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A\cap B$.

If $x\in A\cap B$ then $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$ so $x\in A$.

If $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ by assumption so now $x\in A\cap B$.

1. is similar.